# make external command completion case insensitive when called from within Vim

Tags: autocompletion, external-command, letter-case

I've been learning Vi/Vim for some month and, at the moment, I'm editing many files at once splitting the window, jumping from one buffer to the others. I find it very useful.

One thing I don't like is when I have to execute commands in the shell from within vim. I use, for example `:!make`. This is easy to do. But when I have to run some executable I'd like to use command completion regardless of the case of the letters of the name. For instance, suppose I have to run an MPI program with `:!mpirun -np 8 Convection1D`; actually I'm not so fast in typing the parts `:!` and `-np`, but I could save time by using command completion for the name of the executable. The obstacle is the capital letter (or letters); it'b be very good if I was allowed to type `:!mpir<tab> -np 8 con<tab><enter>` (especially considering that I can press tab repeatedly to view successive completions).

Comment: `" I use, for example :!make. This is easy to do"` -- you may find the [built-in `:make`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/usr_30.txt.html) command useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that `Convection1D` is a file name, you can use the [`wildignorecase`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27wildignorecase%27) setting, which will Vim ignore case when completing file names and directories. This is available since Vim 7.3.075.

Also note you can use [`:!!`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/various.txt.html#%3a%21%21) to repeat the last `:!` command, which may be useful for you.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! ;)

Answer (score 5):

You can define a new command like `:E` instead of `:!` and write a custom completion function for it (see [`:help :command`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/map.txt.html#user-commands)).

```
command! -nargs=+ -complete=custom,s:CustComp E execute "!" . "<args>"
```

with the function

```
function! <SID>CustComp(ArgLead, CmdLine, CursorPos)
    let l:current = split(a:CmdLine, '\s\+', 1)
    if len(l:current) == 2
        return system("compgen -ac")
    else
        let l:ls = split(system("ls"), "\n")
        return join(filter(ls, join(['v:val =~? "', a:ArgLead, '"'], '')), "\n")
    endif
endfunction
```

This assumes you are using bash, if you are using something different you need to substitute the call to `compgen` (including the flags of course) by some other program that list all possible commands for the given shell.

Now you can instead use `:E mpir<tab> -np 8 con<tab><enter>` and it should work.

Comment: FWIW, [this link](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/151118) provides more information about `compgen`.